# How do I delete a suggested kanji conversion from Mozc?

Tags: 16.04, input, japanese, mozc, kanji

How do I delete 取り越し苦労 from Mozc's list of suggested kanji conversions for  とりこし?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the suggestions are provided from other Google Japanese Input Method users.  I'd think Mozc server import updates sometimes. (I am not sure about this, please ask Google about it.)
You can either turn suggestions on/off and increase or decrease number of suggestions.

While you turned off Mozc suggestion, then you can edit somehow the dictionary for purging 取り越し苦労, then you will have to input one by one 取り+越し+苦労